# Questions about economics statistics

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask the question: "Where can I find a list with public debt of UK, by year? (or by fiscal year)".

Can I ask such a question here?

To me it looks like it makes sense to ask such questions here. But then, if I can ask this, then I can also ask the same question about France, Germany, Italy, Russia, China, India, Indonesia and so on. And while you might agree that those questions fit in this site, you will probably think that the volume of questions can get too high.

Thanks

Comment: We have a tag just for this type of question: `data-request`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally data questions have been ontopic here. Perhaps you want to make a less specific request, such that the question is more usable for future visitors too,

> Where can I find a list with public debt of European countries such as the UK, by year? (or by fiscal year)".

Comment: Good news, thanks! Yes, less specific questions helps preventing a flood of questions.